# taking employees data from the active directory into html page in the sharepoint

Tags: rest, sharepoint, active-directory

i have a sharepoint intranet site for my company and i have made a new design for team page using HTML and CSS (the HTML page is in a web part in the sharepoint).
how can i take employees data from the active directory into my html page?

i want to insert the date from active directory into this:

```
<div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
         <h4 class="card-title">William</h4>
         <p class="card-text">Tel.: 0000000000
           <br>Fax: 000000000000
           <br>Mobil: 00000000000
           <br>E-Mail:  William@w.com</p>
</div>
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you configure User Profile Sync and then read user profile by REST api.

[User Profile Synchronization reference](https://blog.trigent.com/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-synchronization-with-active-directory/)

Then, get users by `/_api/web/siteusers`

Then, get user profile by `/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='domain\username'` [Rererence here.](https://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/sharepoint-2013-get-userprofile.html)

Comment: thanks it works :)
but with this code the user can see only his data (it should see the all users data).
it seems that the user needs a permission, how can i solve this?